# Understanding 「自信があれば半ば成功したも同然だ。」

Tags: translation

In

> 自信があれば半ば成功したも同然だ。
>
> Confidence is half the battle. (Idiomatic translation)

I'm having trouble getting to the idiomatic translation.

It seems like a good literal translation of the clause before も is:

> 自信があれば半ば成功した
>
> If one has self-confidence, one does success halfly.

1. What role is も playing? Translating it as "too" or "also" seems a bit awkward to me (i.e. "if one has self-confidence, one does success halfly *too*" is a bit weird?).
2. What is the 同然だ doing at the end?  Does it mean something like: "it is natural", so that the overall sentence becomes: "it is natural that if one has self-confidence, one does success halfly"?

Comment: Do you have context?

Comment: @JimmyYang It's from an [IMABI tutorial on conditionals](https://www.imabi.net/theconditionals.htm). It's listed as a proverb.

Answer (score 2):

～も同然だ should be [learned as a set phrase](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%82%E5%90%8C%E7%84%B6%E3%81%A0-mo-douzen-da-meaning/), but to break down,

- This も is yet another example of [exclamatory-も](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/32886). Here it's close to "even".
- 同然 is a noun (no-adjective) meaning "virtually/effectively the same".

So 半ば成功したも同然だ means (事実上)半ば成功したのと同じだ, or "(It's even) virtually the same as having half-succeeded."

In this pattern, a nominalizer is usually not present after the verb because of [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/64669/5010), but you may occasionally see an explicit の (e.g., 成功したのも同然だ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your example, do you know why after nomalizing with の, the sentence is then marked with と (as opposed to は, が, or に)?

Comment: You have asked about it: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97767/5010 See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52564/5010